# Elasticsearch: Exact multiple match phrases on same field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin

I want the following query to return results where exact phrases separated by OR match in a particular field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "positions",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "positions.companyname",
                "query": "microsoft OR gartner OR IBM"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "positions.title",
                "query": "(Chief Information Security Officer) OR (Chief Digital Officer)"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "positions.title": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results should contain exact **Chief Information Security Officer** OR **Chief Digital Officer**,

but not ***Chief* *Digital* Marketing *Officer*** OR ***Chief* *Information* *Officer*** as it is currently being returned.

Also, the field may not necessarily have the exact phrase to be searched.
For example:

"CIO Chief Information Officer" -> FALSE

"Head at Digital - Chief Digital Officer" -> TRUE

"Former lead Chief Information Security Officer" -> TRUE

"Chief Information Officer" -> False

I guess the point I am trying to make is those phrases should always be next to each other(proximity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would do it.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "positions",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "positions.companyname",
                "query": "microsoft OR gartner OR IBM"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "positions.title": "chief information security officer"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "positions.title": "chief digital officer"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**match_phrase** makes sure that the exact phrase is being searched. To match multiple phrases on the same field, use **bool** operator with **should** condition.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case I would suggest you to use [match_phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase) inside a [bool query's](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) should clause.

Something like this should work:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "text": "Chief Information Security Officer"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "text": "Chief Digital Officer"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using an array or an OR like you could do for a query_string and terms respectively? The only concern is that the query would get too big.